# Method Overloading in PHP 5.6 or any facility in Laravel 5.1 for this?

Tags: oop, overloading, laravel-5.1, php-5.6

is "Method Overloading" facility implemented on PHP 5.6 or any custom facility in Laravel 5.1 ? if not , when it's going to implement .

Because that OOP facility is very helpful for PHP users.